# Is it possible in Scala to define a dependent type like list with a certain first element, last element, or list with a certain length?

Tags: scala, idris, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

To clarify the question, there are languages supporting dependent types, like Idris. Scala supports path dependent types which covers part of it, but it is not clear for me how could one implement such a thing as a list with a certain value as first element or as length. I also know about Shapeless. So I am wondering if there is a realistic way to encode such a type, using any Scala libraries, for maximum expressivity. The application is an exercise of finding paths within a graph between two specific nodes n1 and n2. So to increase the type safety of the program I am trying to specify that the result are lists of nodes starting with n1 and ending with n2, and also when combining two lists, from n1 to n3 and n3 to n2, where n3 is a node in between, how to also assert through the types that the resulting list is having the length equal to the sum of the united lists. Thanks

Comment: look at https://github.com/fthomas/refined